# How can I convert a one to many optional relationship to a one to one require relationship codefirst?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework

I have a database that contains a one-to-many relationship that is optional. I want to convert this relationship to a one-to-one required. For example one fish is required to have one tank to exist and once that fish has a tank no other fish can have that tank. But one tank can exist without one fish. I would like to preserve the data I have. My issue is when I try doing update-database; entity framework now sees that I have two id's which makes sense because the foreign key would become the primary key of the fish table. How can I work around this?

I'm using C# and SQL Server.

Comment: it is not clear what you want to do ? your fish + tank is probably a bad example, cause 1 fish can only link to 1 tank, and 1 tank can probably link to 0 or many fishes.

Comment: I want 1 tank to link to 0 or 1 fish

Comment: so right now you have many fishes in a tank, and you want to have 0 or 1 fish in that tank ? Then it's not possible to preserve all data, or you'll have to kill some fishes or add some tanks. This also makes very few sense with that example, and may be a data model issue...

Comment: well the problem is the database was originally created by someone else using codefirst who did not know how to properly create a one to one relationship. Each fish does only have 1 tank in the database but I'm trying to correct the model

Answer (score 0):

If it's truly going to be a one:one relationship, the easiest way to handle it is to store them in the same record:  e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE Tank
(
    tank_id    Int IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    fish_id    Int NULL
)
```

(A tank with no fish would have a NULL fish_id value)

Comment: i'm trying to maintain a current database and its data and edit one relationship using code first

Comment: @caseysebben  
I'm not sure I understand:  you want to maintain the current database structure, but enforce a one:one or one:zero relationship?

Comment: basically the two tables have a one to many relationship but it should be a one to one relationship and i'm trying to change it using entity framework but it wot, because my fish table already has a fish Id for all its columns and to make the relationship entity framework is trying to make the foreign tank_id the id for the fish table and call it fish Id

Comment: I'm finding this kind of hard to picture:  sounds like a bear to maintain, though.   It sounds as though the entities no longer suite the business requirements.    I'm guessing you'll have to use a trigger to enforce the tank-->fish rules, because the data architecture is really built for a one-->many tank/fish relationship.  Either that, or re-work the entity model, which would be pretty painful.

Comment: yeah i'm going to have to rework the entity model was hoping there would of been an easy quick way to get around this but doesn't sound like there is.